# Drupal imagecache is not working for the first time

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

i am using image cache for my banner image in newsletter.Am uploading and sending the image to mail. The problem is that the image is not loading for the first time. If i again come and edit the page it will send a mail with proper image

```
$output = "
<html>
   <body>";

$output.= theme( 'imagecache', 'banner_img', 'images/motel_wright-1.1.png', 'Wright Motel', 'Wright Motel' );

$output.= "
   </body>
 </html>";

 print $output;
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems. Few suggestions:

1) As you are using the theme function you might need to rebuild the registry. Try

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/drupal_theme_rebuild/7

2) If the above fails you will need to use xdebug and find out which function in drupal was not triggered in the first place.

Do post your finding here.